# Is it possible to access the speaker in the DualShock 4 controller without the PS4 kit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, playstation

I'm currently working on a game in unity which we want to use the special features of the DualShock 4 controller. We have yet to contact Sony, but we wanted to make a prototype before we do that. We've managed to make most of the features work thanks to the [Rewired](https://guavaman.com/projects/rewired/) plugin, but it seems to lack an option to access the speaker in the controller.

Has anyone found a way to access the speaker without the PS4 kit? Is it even possible?

Thanks
Leonard

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that currently there is no feature in Rwired to use the Dualshock 4 speaker.

Here you can find the special Dualshock 4 features you can use: http://guavaman.com/projects/rewired/docs/api-reference/html/T_Rewired_ControllerExtensions_DualShock4Extension.htm

Comment: We encountered the absence of that function. We were wondering if there are more possibilities than rewired.

Comment: I looked for that as well and I couldn't find anything of the sort, my apologies.

Comment: thanks for your time and effort